# не удаётся скомпилировать bpf программу

Tags: linux, c

вот код.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>

#define SEC(NAME) __attribute__((section(NAME), used))

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int bpf_prog(void *ctx) {
        char msg[] = "Hello, BPF World!";
        bpf_trace_printk(msg, sizeof(msg));
        return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

вот makefile

```
C=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
S=/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux
M=/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/
MO=/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/usr/include/
all:
        clang -O2 -target bpf -c bpf.c -I${S} -I${C} -I${M} -I${MO} -o bpf.o
```

вот ошибка

```
clang -O2 -target bpf -c bpf.c -I/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/ -I/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/usr/include/ -o bpf.o
In file included from bpf.c:1:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux/bpf.h:9:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux/workqueue.h:9:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux/timer.h:5:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux/list.h:9:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux/kernel.h:8:
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/include/linux/linkage.h:8:10: fatal error: 'asm/linkage.h' file not found
#include <asm/linkage.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [makefile:6: all] Error 1
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так ничего не выводит же.

Comment: есть asm-generic, но не помогает.

Comment: Насколько я вижу в выводе find этот файл находится в ряде каталогов. Попробуйте тот, что соответствует вашей архитектуре

Comment: @avp у меня find не выдал ничего. архитектура x86_64, помогите.

Comment: звёздочку пропустил: `$ find /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/ -path \*asm/linkage.h`. т.е., скорее всего, добавлять надо `/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-48/arch/x86/include/`

Comment: `clang` — о, да вы смелый экспериментатор. а что, программу clang уже совсем-совсем добили до того состояния, чтобы с исходниками программы linux работать?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так только он с bpf может работать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin теперь новые ошибки. блин. вот проблема скомпилировать bpf. почему так сложно блин.

Comment: @xverizex, ну вообще aleksandr barakin правильно сказал: единственный компилятор, который гарантированно собирает ядро Linux — это GCC, потому что в ядре очень интенсивно используются специфичные для GCC расширения. Идут попытки компиляции с помощью Clang, но, насколько я знаю, пока все не очень стабильно. Крайне советую не искать приключений и воспользоваться GCC.

Comment: @xverizex, я с BPF никогда не работал (да и вообще только сейчас о нем услышал), но [судя по всему](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=51457) GCC 10 уже умеет его компилировать.

Comment: Я немного почитал про BPF и, мне кажется, вы делаете что-то не то. Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно сначала написать eBPF программу, затем скомпилировать ее с помощью Clang или GCC в eBPF байткод, затем написать программу на любом языке программирования (который может делать системные вызовы к ядру), и с помощью системного вызова ядра `bpf()` передать этот скомпилированный байткод в ядро, которое его уже будет исполнять.

Comment: [Здесь](https://ebpf.io/what-is-ebpf) находится официальная документация по eBPF.